# Create simple shell in C with a "Set prompt" command

Tags: c, shell, prompt

```
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 1024
#define SPACES " \t\r\n"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
char line[MAX_LENGTH];
char *cmd;
char *PROMPT = "SUPER SHELL!!";

while(1){
    printf(PROMPT);
    if (!fgets(line, MAX_LENGTH, stdin)) break;

    //parse and execute commands

    if((cmd = strtok(line, SPACES))){
    // clean errors
    errno=0;
    if (strcmp(cmd, "quit") ==0){
    break;
    }
    else if(strcmp(line, "Set Prompt") == 0){
    char *arg = strtok(0, SPACES);
    if (!arg){
        fprintf(stderr, "You were missing a prompt. \n");
    }
    else {PROMPT =arg;
  }
    }
  else system(line);
  if(errno) perror ("Command failed. sorry");
  }
  return 0;
  }
```

I am writing a program in which I have to write my own shell in C.
There must be two commands : quit, which quits the program, and Set Prompt which changes the prompt.
For some reason quit works but Set prompt does not.
How can I fix this?
Thank you

Comment: Your code is very messy. Your problem with "Set Prompt" may be caused by Set and Prompt being read as two inputs.

Comment: Yes, that does seem to be the problem but I don't know how to separate it

Comment: Alright, it is a disaster. http://pastebin.com/2rcZBYUV. I have attempted to format the code and fix naming conventions, but I think you need to learn a bit more before trying something like this. Start small, and add gradually.

Answer (score 0):

Your program indeed seems to have a lot of problems.

Trying to give you some hints, where to improve without solving the whole exercise for you, here some points I stumbled across:

**Gemeral problems**

The program doesn't compile!

1. missing closing brace (most probably on line 35) resulting in:

   `error: expected declaration or statement at end of input`
2. missing include of `stdio.h` resulting in:

   `error: ‘stdin’ undeclared (first use in this function)`
   ...
3. the last one rather a result of the `-Werror` switch used in my compilation attempt:

   `error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]`

   Nevertheless it might not be the worst idea to change `printf(PROMPT);` on line 13. (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string)

**Logic problems**

1. the block following

   `else if(strcmp(line, "Set Prompt") == 0){` on line 24

   will never be executed as the prior call to `strtok()` will have replaced any input of the form "*Set Prompt whatever...*" with "*Set\0Prompt whatever...*" not(!) with  "*Set Prompt\0whatever...*"
2. Even after fixing this issue there will still be some spooky behavior left.

   To reproduce try changing the set prompt command to "SetPrompt" in your code and start a session. I'd be surprised if you came up with a different result than me:

   ```
   SUPER SHELL!!SetPrompt myprompt:
   myprompt:what the hell is going on here?
   sh: 1: what: not found
   ell is going on here?
   quit
   ```

   **Hint:** the simple assignment on line 29 `else {PROMPT =arg;` will not do, as the memory `arg` is pointing to will be overwritten the next time `fgets(line, MAX_LENGTH, stdin)` gets called on line 14.

   Try to reserve some extra memory for the prompt string and look up `strcpy()`